# How to deduce the result $\zeta(2k)_{k\to \infty} \to 1$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

While studying Analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol Introduction to analytic number theory , theorem 12.18  which is related to Bernoulli Numbers I cannot deduce how Apostol writes -

> $\zeta(2k)_{k\to \infty} \to 1$
>   Can it be deduced from this result 
>   [image]

If yes, can someone please tell how

Comment: Nothing simpler using series? :-)

Comment: (Apostol writes "$(23)$ follows from the fact that $\zeta(2k)\to 1$ as $k\to \infty$" not the other way...)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni. *Happy New Year !*

Comment: Happy New Year @Claude and glad to continue observing the regularity of your rep. progression at SE! Wishing you too Fun and a Great Continuation,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @RaymondManzoni notes, that's not Apostol's strategy. It's easiest to prove $\lim_{s\to\infty}\zeta(s)=1$ by the squeeze theorem viz.$$n^{-s}\le\int_{n-1}^nx^{-s}ds\implies\zeta(s)\le1+\int_1^\infty x^{-s}ds=1+\frac{1}{s-1}$$for $s>1$.